# I am trying to add object and remove object to UIStackView in tableview cell on selection of row - it only works one time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistackview

So I am trying to add UIDatePicker to UIStackView inside UITableView cell using delegate -didSelectRowAtIndexPath. When I select row and deselect that row, it works but only once and not repeat that action again.

Stack View is inside tableview cell and contains a tag.
Date Picker is in scene dock.

*In -didSelectRowAtIndexPath method I am checking if stack view contains date picker if not than add it else remove it. It is working only once.*

Here are the codes:

```
 #import "MyTableViewController.h"

@interface MyTableViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *extraPicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIStackView *stackView; //tag 100

@end

@implementation MyTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

}

#pragma addPickerViewToStackView

-(void)addPickerViewToStackView{

    [_stackView addArrangedSubview:_extraPicker];
}

#pragma mark - remove picker
-(void)removePickerFromStackView{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                     animations:^{ [_extraPicker setAlpha:0];
                         [_extraPicker.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:self.view.frame.size.width].active = true;
                         [_stackView removeArrangedSubview:_extraPicker];
                         [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
                     }];
}




#pragma mark - picker date changed
-(IBAction)pickerValeChanged:(id)sender{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return 3;
    }else if (section == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"otherCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Starts";

    if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"pickerCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        _stackView = (UIStackView*) [cell viewWithTag:100];
        return cell;
    }

    return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [_extraPicker setAlpha:1];

    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        if ([_extraPicker isDescendantOfView:_stackView]) {
            [self removePickerFromStackView];
        }else if (![_extraPicker isDescendantOfView:_stackView]){
        [self addPickerViewToStackView];
        }

    }


    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}


@end
```

Answer (score 3):

After reading UIStackView document on Apple website I came to know about this important information:

> This method removes the provided view from the stack’s
>   arrangedSubviews array. The view’s position and size will no longer be
>   managed by the stack view. However, this method does not remove the
>   provided view from the stack’s subviews array; therefore, the view is
>   still displayed as part of the view hierarchy.
>
> To prevent the view from appearing on screen after calling the stack’s
>   removeArrangedSubview: method, explicitly remove the view from the
>   subviews array by calling the view’s removeFromSuperview method, or
>   set the view’s hidden property to YES.

So my mistake was not to remove _extraPicker from superView. After adding this code in -removePickerFromStackView everything is working as it should.

> [_extraPicker removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 0):

You have added [_extraPicker setAlpha:0] while removing, make sure you have set required alpha to your view while adding.

Comment: If alpha would have been the root cause, still Stack View should have grown when extraPicker was added to it as alpha do not change the frame size.

Comment: can you please show code in  addArrangedSubview and removeArrangedSubview methods.

Comment: They are the default class methods of UIStackView that I am calling on instance of UIStackView.

Comment: Hey Narayana35, I have solved the error and posted the explanation.